# Send SMS with accents

Tags: android, sms

I send SMS with this code

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("Numerber", null, "Text to send", null, null);
```

It works pretty well in English, but if I use Spanish it fails. After many tries I found out that the message sent got cropped if the "Text to send" contains accents like "á, é, í, ó, ú"

Of course those accents are needed in Spanish in a proper way of writing, so any idea about this?

Comment: Obviously the problem is connected to encoding. Are you sure you are using UTF-8, otherwise can you convert to it?

Comment: Apparently using `sendMultipartTextMessage` instead of `sendTextMessage` results in correct encoding support (See the dupe link)

Comment: Keep in mind-  sending those accents requires you to use unicode, so you go down to a max of 70 chars per message.  Some users don't like that, if their message is being sent

Comment: Try this: Html.fromHtml(new String(myString.getBytes("UTF-8"))).toString(); and SMS message it looks perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all of you. Yes, it is what you said.
Here is the solution:

```
ArrayList<String> arrSMS = smsManager.divideMessage("Text to send");
smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage("Number", null, arrSMS, null, null);
```