# Android ACTION_SEND with special unicode characters

Tags: java, android, unicode

I am trying to send text using an intent. I thought it was straight-forward:

```java
public Intent getIntent() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, ri.activityInfo.name));
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain"); 
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getText());
    return intent;
}

private String getText(){
    // the emoji can be one of many. I removed all that for brevity 
    final int unicode = 0x1F3C5;
    final String emoji = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(unicode));
    // final String emoji = "\n1F3C5"; //didn't work either
    // I also tried using HTML here but I think I have some wires crossed, so I am not ruling that out yet
    return textPartOne + " " + emoji + " " + textPartTwo;
}
```

As you can see, the `EXTRA_TEXT` has a special character in it (an emoji). When the text sends from device `A` the emoji appears like I expect in the message. But on device `B` (the receiver) the text shows some madness *(usually in two different messages)*:

> @.£¡ù¿    ¡        ¡ |      |      <   |     |    | \ <     |  [  ¡  { ¡  [  ¡
>
> @H£(ù@æ@a@¤¥¡
>
> ¡9@ü@Hù@Θ@=@ø¥p
>
> ¡6@Ö@Δì¿    ¡   |

It doesn't matter if I send the message from device `A` to device `B` or `B` to `A`. I get the same results either way, so I believe it isn't an issue with the emoji not being supported.

Now, if I remove all but the emoji code:

> Xäx&

If I remove the emoji code altogether it works like a charm.

<sub>But the client has *gotta* have those emojis...</sub>

---

*Some other things that may be of note:*

- I am using [this to manage what intents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18068122/1642079) I am presenting to the user. They could pick MMS, email, Twitter, Facebook or whatever really. I need to support all of these
- I am getting the [special characters from Emojipedia](http://emojipedia.org/)
- **I am not displaying the emojis anywhere in the app.** They will be shown in Text message, Email, or Facebook/Twitter feed.
- There is already an iOS variant of this app who is successfully doing this.

I [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134619/how-to-send-emojis-image-smileys-in-a-chat-or-message-app-in-android/27183457#27183457) tried [nearly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893796/how-set-emoji-by-unicode-in-android-textview) a [dozen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943491/send-sms-with-accents?noredirect=1&lq=1) different [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233461/android-unicode-charset-problems-when-sending-an-sms-sendtextmessage) with [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592817/ios-emojis-show-as-unicode-characters-in-push-notification-using-java?rq=1) avail.
 Is there anyone that may have some insight on how to properly send special characters?

---

#### Edit:

As you can see, I am sending the emoji I desire. But the result is far from what I expect. This is a screenshot of an emulator sending a text to itself. [image]

Here are *some* of the ways I have tried

```java
    String attempt1 = "--";
    try {
        attempt1 = Html.fromHtml(new String("&#x1F3C5".getBytes("UTF-8"))).toString();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final int codePoint = 0x26F7;
    final String attempt2 = new String(new int[]{codePoint}, 0, 1);

    final String attempt3 = new String(Character.toChars(codePoint));
    final String attempt4 = "\u26F7";
```

All result in:

> &n

If I add text to these:

```java
final String attempt4 = "COME ON: \u26F7";
```

I get this:

> @Σ£(ù@æ@s@@£ Å¡7@X£¿ù¿

Which makes total sense <sub><sup>*he said sarcastically*</sup></sub>

Comment: Check this answer to send emoji https://stackoverflow.com/a/27183457/8084578

Comment: where you display this emojis?

Comment: @JaydeepPatel *I* don't display them. They will be displayed in a Text message, email, or Facebook/Twitter feed.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel This has nothing to do with TextViews

Comment: try from here: https://emojipedia.org/face-with-stuck-out-tongue-and-tightly-closed-eyes/

Comment: you will get HEX code with \u, share it as string direct.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel if you see the part of my question that says _"Some other things that may be of note"_. I am already using those hex codes. I have also tried to use them in the string as-is like you suggested. Some codes were one char too long resulting in an incorrect emoji followed by a useless character.

Comment: @ChadBingham , Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @RossRogers, nope, I never did. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You can use intents, which are messages sent between activities. In a intent you can put all sort of data, String, int, etc.

In your case, in activity2, before going to activity1, you will store a String message this way :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity2.this, activity1.class);
intent.putExtra("message", getText());
startActivity(intent);
```

In activity1, in onCreate(), you can get the String message by retrieving a Bundle (which contains all the messages sent by the calling activity) and call getString() on it :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String message = bundle.getString("message");
```

Then you can set the text in the TextView:

```
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_resource_textview);    
txtView.setText(message);
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: No, this doesn't answer my problem with special characters.